# Android - Launch Widget from Activity

Tags: android, android-widget, android-activity, android-appwidget

So, the widget is already added on the screen, I'm wondering if there is a way to go/launch the widget from an activity?
Thanks.

Comment: Launch the widget from an activity? What? The widget is on the homescreen, how would you launch that? You could... close your app, that would show the home screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy, destroy your activity by call :

```
finish();
```

=========

## EDIT

so basically you need a function behave like home button. your application will put in background and show the home screen.

```
moveTastToBack(true);
```

or

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
this.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: But there are still a lot of activities in the background, doing that will just close the current activity and it will then display the previous displayed activity.